# Gradient Vector Question?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The temperature in some three-dimensional body is modeled by the equation $$f(x,y,z)=49-x^2-y^2-z^2$$
Find the largest rate at which the temperature is increasing when T=0.

I believe this is a gradient vector question, but when I do the problem I feel like the answer I got is very incorrect.

---

$$f(x,y,z)=<-2x,-2y,-2z>$$ since you derive for $f_x, f_y, f_z$

Since T=0

$$f(0,0,0)=<0,0,0>$$

$$||f(0,0,0)||=0$$

Am I missing something in the equation, did something wrong, or is this not even a gradient vector question and a completely different type of question?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem says that *the temperature* is $0$, not that $x,y,$ and $z$ are $0$.  (What kind of region does
$$
0 = f(x,y,z) = 49 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2
$$
define?)  Then you want to maximize $\|\nabla f(x,y,z)\|$ subject to this constraint.